# Python Regex for Negative Lookaround for multiline content

Tags: python, regex

I am new to Python. I am working on LaTeX file, which contain lot of Math, Programming code, etc. I have replace multiple space `" +"` by `" "`. But i need to ignore in certain part of my code. For example:

Normal Text:    `"Hai, I am    New to       Python"`. I have replace multi space by single space by `"Hai, I am New to Python"`. This regex was applied to whole document. But i need to ignore multi space in certain LaTeX Tag. For example

```
Hai, I am    New to       Python
\begin{lstlisting}[title=Sample]
      print("Hai, I am    New to       Python")
      def Code(a):
          print(a)
      Code("Hai, i am new to Perl")
\end{lstlisting}
```

After my code multi space was changed to single space between `\begin{lstlisting}` to `\end{lstlisting}`

```
"Hai, I am New to Python"
\begin{lstlisting}[title=Sample]
 print("Hai, I am New to Python")
 def Code(a):
 print(a)
 Code("Hai, i am new to Perl")
\end{lstlisting}
```

How to ignore python regex between `\begin{lstlisting}` to `\end{lstlisting}`?

Comment: I'd suggest not doing this with regex -- you'll keep running into boundary cases that are handled wrongly. Instead [find a LaTeX parser](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/564420/is-there-a-python-module-for-parsing-latex).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A proper LaTeX parser is the way to go but this may be a 'good enough' solution. See what you think.

```py
import re

text = '''
Hai, I am    New to       Python
\\begin{lstlisting}[title=Sample]
      print("Hai, I am    New to       Python")
      def Code(a):
          print(a)
      Code("Hai, i am new to Perl")
\\end{lstlisting}
'''
  
text = re.sub(r' +(?!(?:(?!\\begin\{lstlisting\}).)*\\end\{lstlisting\})', ' ', text, flags=re.DOTALL)

print(text)
```

It works by not replacing the spaces if `\end{lstlisting}` appears ahead in the string without `\begin{lstlisting}` appearing before it.